# Insert date difference field in MS-Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, automation

I need to insert in CV created in MS Word document the age of the people.

I know the birth date of the person.

Is there a way to insert a field that will automatically calculates the age?

- Johny Walker, `{FIELD=NOW-BIRTHDATE}` years.

Comment: check this [link](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T009541_Age_Calculation_with_Fields.html)

Comment: does not work...

Comment: Would you be willing to create an Excel spreadsheet with the names and birthdates (and calculated ages) and Paste Link into your Word document?  It will look a lot like a regular Word table.  You will need to remember to make all your updates in the Excel file.